# Creating resizable WPF control using XAML

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to create a WPF control that contains elements (rectangles and ellipses) that scale and align as the container resizes.  As an example, if an ellipse is set to align horizontally to the right, it always stays on the right.  As the container is vertically resized, so do the child elements.

I've been looking at control tutorials for a couple hours now with some insight, but still nothing that I can get to work.  Is this something that can be done entirely in XAML?

Comment: Can you add some more detail about what your goal is in using this control? Is the set of shapes fixed or is it intended that consumers of the control or some data specify them?

Comment: It's a fixed set.  It's a mission-specific representation of something I've done in a desktop app.  I'm trying to move an element of it to Silverlight and/or WPF for the experience of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should place your elements in `Canvas` panel. By setting attached properties `Canvas.Left`, `Canvas.Right`, `Canvas.Top`, `Canvas.Bottom` on your sub-elements you can align them. E.g:

```
<Canvas>
    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="20" Width="30" Height="30" Fill="Red"  />
    <Ellipse Canvas.Right="20" Canvas.Bottom="20" Width="30" Height="30" Fill="Blue"  />
</Canvas>
```